# embedded interface in a struct behaves in a very weird manner

Tags: go

I find hard to understand how Go works internally. There are some cases where it exhibits weird behavior.

```
type TestInterface interface {
   Walk()
}

type A struct {
}

func (a *A) Walk() {
   fmt.Println("hello world")
}

type B struct {
   TestInterface
}

func main() {
    var a *A
    b := B{}

    a.Walk() // This will not panic even though a is nil
    b.Walk() // This will panic.
}
```

Since `b` embeds `TestInterface`, `b.Walk()` will internally call `Walk` method on struct `A` in a similar way as `a.Walk()` is called.

Why is it then that one works and the other panics?

Comment: adding to @mkopriva's answer if you embed `A` in struct `B` methods of A will be automatically promoted to `B`. then you cann call `b.Walk()` and will work fine. But be careful if you decalre `b` as `var b *B` this will give nill pointer error as you are trying to access field `A`'s method of nil type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Go doc mentioned about [Method_declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations), Methods are bound to the base type of the receiver.

> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the
> method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic
> parameter, the receiver. Its type must be a defined type T or a
> pointer to a defined type T. T is called the receiver base type. A
> receiver base type cannot be a pointer or interface type and it must
> be defined in the same package as the method. The method is said to be
> bound to its receiver base type and the method name is visible only
> within selectors for type T or *T.

So your Methods are bound to *main.A type and type of `var a` also *main.A. So it is allowed to call `Walk()` method. But if you use `a` as a value inside the method, it will also panic.

Inside your `b` of `B` type, `TestInterface`'s default type is nil and that's why It is panicing. You have to inject interface implemented type into `B` to avoid panicing.

```
func main() {
    var a *A
    b := B{TestInterface:a}

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a), b)
    a.Walk() // This will not panic even though a is nil
    b.Walk() // This will not panic anymore.
}
```

run in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SUA6j80jQ94)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mkopriva comment above, I modified the program in the following way and it makes sense now. It also means that nil in Go has a type associated with it.

````
type TestInterface interface {
   Walk()
}

type A struct {
}

func (a *A) Walk() {
   fmt.Println("hello world")
}

type B struct {
   TestInterface
}

func main() {
    var a *A
    
    b := B{TestInterface: a}
    
    // both will not panic
    a.Walk() 
    // TestInterface is still nil as a is nil.
    b.Walk() 
}```
````

Comment: Note that `TestInterface`, once it holds the type info, regardless of the underlying value, is not `nil` anymore. It is a common source of confusion that an interface whose underlying typed value is `nil` returns `false` when compared to `nil`. See: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/vhcmHvjJIjp